# Strange syntax error in the migration file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I retrieve this strange error and I can't explain:

```
→ rake db:migrate:redo
rake aborted!
SyntaxError: .../db/migrate/20141208102936_transition_reviews_to_be_polymorphic.rb:20: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end
```

This is the source:

```
class TransitionReviewsToBePolymorphic < ActiveRecord::Migration

#   class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
#   end

  def change
    # Review.reset_column_information

    reversible do |dir|
#       dir.up do
#     #     Review.find_each do |review|
#     #       review.reviewable_id = review.schedule_id
#     #       review.reviewable_type = 'Schedule'
#     #       review.save
#     #     end
#       end
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: I don't see the problem except the (non-printable chars) but just try to debug not commenting out the code but cropping it out part-by-part. i.e. from the beginning leave `class`, then add `def`, the add `reversible`

Comment: I did that... I can't explain this.

Comment: so that was the non-breaking spaces, as it was shewn by @stefan, remove them =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your file contains several [non-breaking spaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space) (shown as underscores):

```
class TransitionReviewsToBePolymorphic < ActiveRecord::Migration

#   class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
# __end

  def change
    # Review.reset_column_information

    reversible do |dir|
# ______dir.up do
#     #     Review.find_each do |review|
#     #       review.reviewable_id = review.schedule_id
#     #       review.reviewable_type = 'Schedule'
#     #       review.save
#     # ____end
#       end
____end
  end

end
```